# Search mongodb data using the lt & gt comparators on the date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, date

```js
const queryMatch = {departureDate: {$gte: new Date(query.departureDateMin),$lte: new Date(query.departureDateMax)}};
const flightsByCriteria = await this.flightModel.find(queryMatch).exec();
```

The above request returns an empty table.
And yet I get data with mongodbCompass using  `ISODate(dateString)`  instead of `new Date(dateString)`

I don't know where the problem lies in my request ?
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.find({
  departureDate: {
    $gte: new Date(query.departureDateMin),
    $lte: new Date(query.departureDateMax),
  },
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the dates from the client side in ISO format, so the server would not covert them to the server local time.

When you are sending dates from the client, you can just send them with calling `.toISOString()` method:

```
{
  departureDateMin: new Date(departureDateMin).toISOString(),
  departureDateMax: new Date(departureDateMax).toISOString(),
}
```

Then, you can query database like this:

```js
const queryMatch = {
  departureDate: {
    $gte: query.departureDateMin,
    $lte: query.departureDateMax,
  }
};
```

Comment: it always returns an empty array.

Comment: Can you `console.log()` your inputs and add it to the question. Also, try to console log the `new Date(inputs)` and add that one as well.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you try it again?

Comment: there are inputs log: `departureDateMin: '2022-10-10T22:00:00.000Z', departureDateMax: '2022-10-26T22:00:00.000Z'
`

Comment: and new Date(inputs): 
`departureDate: {
    '$gte': 2022-10-10T22:00:00.000Z,
    '$lte': 2022-10-26T22:00:00.000Z
 }`

Comment: Are are you sure you have documents between these values in the database? And did you add `.toISOString()` part in the query object?

Comment: yes I have a document ( with departureDate: `2022-09-10T22:00:00.000Z`) between these two dates.

Yes i used .toISOString() on inputs data from front, i've already emty array .

Comment: it works with   `model.find({departureDate: {$gte: new Date(query.departureDateMin),$lte: new Date(query.departureDateMax)}})`   just after a reboot of the computer with: